# Java: Convert XSD files to Java classes

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xjc, ota

I'm currently using xjc to convert my xsd files in java classes. My app is based on ota-opentravel (http://www.opentravel.org/) standard so I downloaded their xsd files for ota-2016b version and tried to convert all xsd file in java classes. I got the following error:

```
Property "Value" is already defined. 
Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

The following location is relevant to the above error
line 5848 of file:/OTA_CommonTypes.xsd
line 1836 of file:/OTA_Lists.xsd
line 6820 of file:/OTA_CommonTypes.xsd
etc
```

I found a lot of examples how to solve this issue, one of them was to specify .xjb file and add some additional bindings for .xsd files where I have an issue. **This is a good approach for someone who has few .xsd files but for me, who has to convert more than three hundred .xsd files, it seems impossible.**

I also found some maven ota_travel dependencies where I have everything already generated but the latest version that they support is ota_v2014 and I need also version ota_v2015 and ota_v2016.

The command that I used to convert these .xsd files in java classes is:       **sudo xjc -d src/destination/folder1/ source/OTA_HotelResModifyNotifRQ.xsd**

Comment: My personal advice would be not to attempt Java data-binding with a schema as large and complex as OTA. You simply get an unmanageable number of classes.

Comment: The primary purpose of XSD is for specifying exactly what's allowed and what isn't. Operationally, the main purpose is for validating document instances. Another use is for writing schema-aware programs in XQuery or XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching and found following solution:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:version="2.0">

        <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="OpenTravel_2015B_XML/OTA_CommonTypes.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
           <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='CalculationMethod']/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Duration']/xs:complexType">
                <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='Value']">
                    <jxb:property name="ValueToFixError1"/>
                </jxb:bindings>
            </jxb:bindings>
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='MaximumDuration']/xs:complexType">
                <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='Value']">
                    <jxb:property name="ValueToFixError2"/>
                </jxb:bindings>
            </jxb:bindings>
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='StartAndEnd']/xs:complexType/xs:choice/xs:element[@name='Duration']/xs:complexType">
                <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='Value']">
                    <jxb:property name="ValueToFixError3"/>
                </jxb:bindings>
            </jxb:bindings>
            <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OntologyDistanceType']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Distance']/xs:complexType">
                <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='Value']">
                    <jxb:property name="ValueToFixError4"/>
                </jxb:bindings>
            </jxb:bindings> 
        </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

With this binding file XJC will successfully generate, for most of ota version, java classes. For some of ota versions we even do not need this binding file like ota2008b version.

In order to run previous command we just have to add path where is our binding file:
**sudo xjc -b /bindings.xjb -d src/destination/folder1/ source/OTA_HotelResModifyNotifRQ.xsd**